# Подсчитать кол-во файлов в директории и поддиректориях

Tags: php

Доброго дня!
Есть задача подсчитать количество файлов в директории и в поддиректориях. Я соорудил следующее, но что-то мне кажется, что запутался в трех соснах:

```
$dir = '/tmp'
function count_files($dir){
$files1 = scandir($dir);
if($i){$i = $i;}else{$i = 0;}
foreach ($files1 as $key => $value){
if (!in_array($value, array(".", ".."))){
    if(is_file($dir.'/'.$value)){$i = $i + 1;}
    if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$value)){count_files($dir.'/'.$value);}
} 
}
return $i;
}
echo count_files($dir);
```

как же правильно посчитать? Спасибо!

Comment: я поставил точку с запятой в первой строке. и вместо этого чуда `if($i){$i = $i;}else{$i = 0;}` написал `$i = 0;` Что-то считает. или не то считает?

Comment: Если ввести `$i=0;` то при каждом цикле значение будет обнуляться...

Comment: этот оператор вне цикла

Comment: имеется в виду не повтор цикла, а рекурсивный повтор самой функции...

Comment: так в этой переменной и накапливается только сумма на этом уровне. после того, как функция выполнилась, и значение через return был отдано, все переменные, объявленные внутри функции, удаляются. вы не видите внутри функции $i определенные при предыдущих вызовах этой функции

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто

```
$dir = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
printf("В даной директории %d файл(-ов)", iterator_count($dir));
```

Comment: а не вот это `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` или тот тоже во вложенные ходит?

Comment: Надо попробовать. То что вспомнил - то дал. Но если я не ошибаюсь - то и вложенные находит.

Comment: Находит все файлы. Протестировано

Comment: отлично, тогда  +1 :)

Comment: Просто есть проект сейчас у меня. Да и протестит где место нашлось) Протестил - заработало. У меня вот 18 файлов из 18

Comment: Так это считает только в заданной директории, не не в поддиректориях....?

Comment: считает всё, что есть в директории и поддиректориях. У меня папка и 3 подпапки. Сосчитало всё

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо!
Вопрос решился таким образом:

```
$dir = '/tmp';
function count_files($dir){
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$i = 0;
foreach ($files1 as $key => $value){
if (!in_array($value, array(".", ".."))){
    if(is_file($dir.'/'.$value)){$i = $i + 1;}
    if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$value)){$i += count_files($dir.'/'.$value);}
} 
}
return $i;
}
echo count_files($dir);
```